# Ktor WebSocket cannot support Android Turkish locale?

Tags: android, websocket, ktor

It seems that Ktor WebSocket cannot support Android Turkish locale.
The below code is work well other than Turkish locale. It crash when I change device locale to Turkish (I checked 28 locale ​​including Arabic)
Even if I test it on various devices(SS smart phone, Custom device based on AOSP8), but it does not work with only have difference crash location.

Could you please let me know how to do it?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private fun startServer() {
        embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
            install(io.ktor.websocket.WebSockets) {
            }
            routing {
                webSocket("/language") {
                    incoming.consumeEach { frame ->
                        when (frame) {
                            is Frame.Text -> println("######################### ${frame.readText()}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start()
    }

    private val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        install(io.ktor.client.features.websocket.WebSockets)
    }

    private fun connectLocalhost() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                client.ws(host = "localhost", port = 8080, path = "/language") {
                    send(Frame.Text("My name is Hello World"))
                    incoming.consumeEach { frame ->
                        when (frame) {
                            is Frame.Text -> println(frame.readText())
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e:Throwable) {
                println(e.message)
                println("------------------------- ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        startServer()
        connectLocalhost()
    }
}
```

Ktor is being used like this

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
ext.ktor_version = '1.2.5'

maven {url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor"}

implementation "io.ktor:ktor-websockets:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:1.2.5"
implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-websockets:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-js:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktor_version"
```

Here is log for SS Smart Phone

```
04/07 13:40:34: Launching 'app' on samsung SM-G960N.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 25078 on device 'samsung-sm_g960n-22d1af5612037ece'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c3,c257,c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.myapplication 
I/e.myapplicatio: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/ConnectivityManager_URSP: Ursp sIsUrsp=false, sIsCheckUrsp=false, uid=10259
D/Proxy: urspP is null: 10259
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/WindowInsets;->CONSUMED:Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (light greylist, reflection)
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.302 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
E/e.myapplicatio: No implementation found for int io.netty.channel.kqueue.Native.sizeofKEvent() (tried Java_io_netty_channel_kqueue_Native_sizeofKEvent and Java_io_netty_channel_kqueue_Native_sizeofKEvent__)
    No implementation found for int io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.offsetofEpollData() (tried Java_io_netty_channel_epoll_Native_offsetofEpollData and Java_io_netty_channel_epoll_Native_offsetofEpollData__)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.316 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
    13:40:39.317 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Platform: Android
I/System.out: 13:40:39.318 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Java version: 6
I/System.out: 13:40:39.318 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - Platform: Android
W/e.myapplicatio: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (light greylist, reflection)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.319 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
I/System.out: 13:40:39.322 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: unavailable
I/System.out: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory [class java.lang.Object, long, class java.lang.Object, long, long]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2069)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$2.run(PlatformDependent0.java:132)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:43)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:128)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.isAndroid(PlatformDependent0.java:810)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:214)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:82)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.normalizedArch(PlatformDependent.java:1270)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:183)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:57)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.newEpollCreate(Native.java:89)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:38)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.isAvailable(Epoll.java:68)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:186)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.<init>(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:74)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:14)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:12)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:79)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:67)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:36)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer$default(EmbeddedServer.kt:34)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.startServer(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:69)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
I/System.out:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.327 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
I/System.out: 13:40:39.328 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: unavailable (Android)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.329 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/cache (java.io.tmpdir)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.331 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
    13:40:39.332 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
I/System.out: 13:40:39.332 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: true
    13:40:39.333 [main] INFO io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system instability.
I/System.out: 13:40:39.336 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/cache (io.netty.tmpdir)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.337 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.deleteLibAfterLoading: true
    13:40:39.337 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - -Dio.netty.native.tryPatchShadedId: true
I/System.out: 13:40:39.338 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'netty_transport_native_epoll_aarch_64', trying other loading mechanism.
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-usrP3X4x8loS0kKwhhCp0A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-usrP3X4x8loS0kKwhhCp0A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libnetty_transport_native_epoll_aarch_64.so"
I/System.out:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:369)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:43)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:361)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:339)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:186)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:57)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.newEpollCreate(Native.java:89)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:38)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.isAvailable(Epoll.java:68)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:186)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.<init>(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:74)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:14)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:12)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:79)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:67)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:36)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer$default(EmbeddedServer.kt:34)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.startServer(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:69)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
I/System.out:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.342 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - netty_transport_native_epoll_aarch_64 cannot be loaded from java.library.path, now trying export to -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/cache
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-usrP3X4x8loS0kKwhhCp0A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-usrP3X4x8loS0kKwhhCp0A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libnetty_transport_native_epoll_aarch_64.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:349)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:186)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:57)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.newEpollCreate(Native.java:89)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:38)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.isAvailable(Epoll.java:68)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:186)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.<init>(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:74)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:14)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:12)
I/System.out:     at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:79)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:67)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:36)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer$default(EmbeddedServer.kt:34)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.startServer(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:69)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.348 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - Unable to load the library 'netty_transport_native_epoll', trying other loading mechanism.
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-usrP3X4x8loS0kKwhhCp0A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-usrP3X4x8loS0kKwhhCp0A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libnetty_transport_native_epoll.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
I/System.out:     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:369)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:43)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:361)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:339)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:189)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:57)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.newEpollCreate(Native.java:89)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:38)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.isAvailable(Epoll.java:68)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:186)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.<init>(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:74)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:14)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:12)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:79)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:67)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:36)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer$default(EmbeddedServer.kt:34)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.startServer(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:69)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.351 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader - netty_transport_native_epoll cannot be loaded from java.library.path, now trying export to -Dio.netty.native.workdir: /data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/cache
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-usrP3X4x8loS0kKwhhCp0A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-usrP3X4x8loS0kKwhhCp0A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libnetty_transport_native_epoll.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:349)
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:136)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:189)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:57)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.newEpollCreate(Native.java:89)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>(Epoll.java:38)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.isAvailable(Epoll.java:68)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:186)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.<init>(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:74)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:14)
I/System.out:     at io.ktor.server.netty.Netty.create(Embedded.kt:12)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:79)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:67)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer(EmbeddedServer.kt:36)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.EmbeddedServerKt.embeddedServer$default(EmbeddedServer.kt:34)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.startServer(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:69)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
I/System.out: 13:40:39.358 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 16
I/System.out: 13:40:39.368 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.initialSize: 1024
I/System.out: 13:40:39.369 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap - -Dio.netty.threadLocalMap.stringBuilder.maxSize: 4096
I/System.out: 13:40:39.373 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
    13:40:39.374 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
I/System.out: 13:40:39.376 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: unavailable
I/System.out: 13:40:39.390 [main] INFO ktor.application - No ktor.deployment.watch patterns specified, automatic reload is not active
I/System.out: 13:40:39.409 [main] INFO ktor.application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080
D/TcpOptimizer: TcpOptimizer-ON
I/System.out: 13:40:39.419 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - Could not invoke ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName(); Android?
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.defaultProcessId(DefaultChannelId.java:114)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.<clinit>(DefaultChannelId.java:77)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId.newInstance(DefaultChannelId.java:55)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.newId(AbstractChannel.java:100)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.<init>(AbstractChannel.java:72)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.<init>(AbstractNioChannel.java:80)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel.<init>(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:42)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.<init>(NioServerSocketChannel.java:88)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.<init>(NioServerSocketChannel.java:74)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
I/System.out:     at io.netty.channel.ReflectiveChannelFactory.newChannel(ReflectiveChannelFactory.java:44)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:309)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.doBind(AbstractBootstrap.java:271)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:267)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:252)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:129)
        at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:26)
        at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngine$DefaultImpls.start$default(ApplicationEngine.kt:56)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.startServer(MainActivity.kt:41)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:69)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-usrP3X4x8loS0kKwhhCp0A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-usrP3X4x8loS0kKwhhCp0A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved by upgrading ktor version to 1.3.2 or higher